# pass CSS .class as a parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

the goal here is onclick of 1.gif, everything with .panel1 class disappears(style.display.none), and everything with a .panel2 class becomes visable (style.display.inline)

I'm new at this..so I think its just a syntax issue with '  ' or maybe "  "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>main</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
    .panel1 {display:inline;}
    .panel2 {display:none;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function panelTransition(panelOut,panelIn)
        {
        document.getElementByClass(panelIn).style.display="inline";
        document.getElementByClass(panelOut).style.display="none";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="panel1" src=1.gif onclick="panelTransition(panel1,panel2)" />
<img class="panel2" src=2.gif />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind asking me this: You are using basic HTML5 standards and no jQuery? =) Why? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `getElementByClass`. It's `getElementsByClassName`, and it returns an array of items, so you'll need to modify your code to loop through them.

```
function panelTransition(panelOut, panelIn) {
    var inPanels = document.getElementsByClassName(panelIn);
    for (var i = 0; i < inPanels.length; i++) {
        inPanels[i].style.display = 'inline';
    }

    var outPanels = document.getElementsByClassName(panelOut);
    for (var i = 0; i < outPanels.length; i++) {
        outPanels[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

If you were using a JavaScript library, like jQuery, this would be much easier to do. Also, as has been mentioned, you need quotes around your arguments to `panelTransition`.

```
<img class="panel1" src=1.gif onclick="panelTransition('panel1', 'panel2')" />
<img class="panel2" src=2.gif />
```

Comment: You might want to update your code so it no longer uses `getElementByClass()` but instead uses `getElementByClassName()`

Comment: this fixed it.  thanks.   here it is hosted  http://23.23.184.26/miller/transitiontest/transitiontest.html

Comment: here it is a little more elaborate http://23.23.184.26/miller/transitiontest/main.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>main</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
    .panel1 {display:inline;}
    .panel2 {display:none;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function panelTransition(panelOut,panelIn)
                {
                    // panelIn gets turned on
                    setDisplay(panelIn,"inline");

                    // panelOut gets turned off
                    setDisplay(panelOut,"none");
                }

                function setDisplay(className,displayState)
                {
                    // retrieve a list of all the matching elements
                    var list = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

                    // step through the list
                    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
                        // for each element, set the display property
                        list[i].style.display = displayState;
                    }                        
                }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="panel1" src="1.gif" onclick="panelTransition('panel1','panel2')" />
<img class="panel2" src="2.gif" onclick="panelTransition('panel2','panel1')" />
</body>

</html>
```

Or you can accomplish the same in jQuery

```
// fires when the page is up and running
$(document).ready(function(){

     // find all the panel1 elements, 
     // attach an on click handler
     $(".panel1").bind("click", function(){ 

            // find all the panel1 elements
            // set their css display property to inline
            $(".panel1").css("display","inline"); 

            // find all the panel2 elements
            // set their css display property to none
            $(".panel2").css("display","none");
     });

     $(".panel2").bind("click", function(){ 
            $(".panel2").css("display","inline"); 
            $(".panel1").css("display","none");
     });
});
```

You can learn all about jQuery here : http://www.jquery.com/

You'll only be able to get your code to run once, as soon as you click a panel1 image all of the panel2 images will disappear, you won't be able to click them back on ever again.

Comment: At this point, I think it'd be better for him to learn about basic programming concepts, before diving into jQuery...

Comment: no...this is helpful.  ive only been studying this for a few days and its already aparrent that jquery is where ill end up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="panel1" src=1.gif onclick="panelTransition('panel1','panel2')" />
```

I think you need quotes there